# c# asp.net line chart - X axis label where y = 0

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I make the X axis labels appear where y = 0. I have a line chart with negative and positive values. Currently the x axis is appearing at the bottom of the chart not where y = 0.

[image]

Below is the code I have to create the following graph so far. I need to try move the X axis labels to the  middle of the chart rather than at the bottom. The negative points should show below the X axis labels if possible.

asp.net

```
            <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" border-width="2px" Width="1200px" Height="600px" ImageType="Png" CanResize="true" CssClass="table  table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive">
            <Titles>
                <asp:Title Text="Data" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt" ForeColor="#007bff"></asp:Title>
            </Titles>
            <Legends>
                <asp:Legend Docking="Bottom" Alignment="Center"></asp:Legend>
            </Legends>



            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                    <AxisX Title="Date" IsMarginVisible="False" TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 10pt"  >
                        <MajorGrid Enabled="false" LineColor="LightGray" />


                    </AxisX>
                    <AxisY Title="" Minimum="-15" Maximum="10" TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 10pt" Interval="5">
                        <MajorGrid Enabled="true" LineColor="LightGray" />
                    </AxisY>
                </asp:ChartArea>

            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
```

C#:

```
private void GetChartData()
{

//Data table created using sql procedure

    List<string> status = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                           select p.Field<string>("Status")).Distinct().ToList();

    foreach (string statuses in status)
    {

        //Get the Event Label
        string[] x = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      where p.Field<string>("Status") == statuses
                      select p.Field<string>("EventLabel")).ToArray();

        //Get the Total of Orders 
        int[] y = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   where p.Field<string>("Status") == statuses
                   select p.Field<int>("Total")).ToArray();

        //Add Series to the Chart.
        Chart1.Series.Add(new Series(statuses));
        Chart1.Series[statuses].IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
        Chart1.Series[statuses].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
        Chart1.Series[statuses].BorderWidth = 2;
        Chart1.Series[statuses].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        Chart1.Series[statuses].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
    }

    Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;

}
```

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Correct - The label is string format as per the image. The issue is i want to move the x axis to where y = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Set Crossing=0 in the AxisY tag and this resolves it